# Interstellar medium shock heating

Tags: special-relativity, radiation, shock-waves, magnetohydrodynamics

How fast would a hypothetical spacecraft need to get to experience significant heating from interaction with the interstellar medium (ISM)?  Significant, in this context, means a steady-state temperature (that at which radiative cooling balances the heat being generated) of a few hundred K or more.  I am considering both the ISM and blueshifted photons here.

The means by which a spacecraft could reach such speeds are immaterial, or if it can be done at all, are irrelevant to this question.

An ideal answer will include a formula from which the temperature can be calculated for any velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Interstellar space has about 100 ions, mostly protons and corresponding electrons, per cubic meter. So assume that we have a surface area of material one square meter in area with $\gamma=2$ or velocity $v=.867c$. The total energy of a proton impacting this surface is $E=\gamma mc^2$ and the kinetic energy is $K=(\gamma-1)mc^2$. In one second this square meter of surface sweeps out a volume of $1.5\times 10^8m^3$ which means it impacts around $1.5\times 10^{10}$ ions. Now the proton has mass $1.7\times 10^{-27}kg$ and if this energy is absorbed in this material it would absorb $2.2\times 10^{-1}$ joules of energy every second. The reader can make a table with higher $\gamma$.

Comment: Does length contraction also need to be considered here?

Comment: Not really, for even if one thinks there is a Lorentz contraction of the distance this $1m^2$ area sweeps out the number of ions in the volume swept out is the same.

Comment: Does ablation add any energy to the remaining material?  That is, any proton or electron hitting the spacecraft at ~0.87c is energetic enough to ionize the surface material.  At lower energies, the energy imparted before ejecting anything is minimal but I am not sure how much this matters at higher energies.